# Remove width and height of img tag in given string in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, image

I have some html string that is coming from telerik radeditor, it may contain images tags with width and height. I want to remove those width and height properties.
How can I do this in code using regex or something else in asp.net?

Comment: please show a sample html string and your desired o/p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of mentions regarding [*not to use regex when parsing HTML*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), so you could use e.g. [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

var images = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
foreach (HtmlNode image in images)
{
    if (image.Attributes["width"] != null)
    {
        image.Attributes["width"].Remove();
    }
    if (image.Attributes["height"] != null)
    {
        image.Attributes["height"].Remove();
    }
}
```

this will remove `width` and `height` attribute from images in your html.

Answer (score 2):

Two Regex replace statements will do the job pretty well:

```cs
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+height\s*=\s*\S+",
        "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+width\s*=\s*\S+",
        "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

(This is a C# snippet - not sure if ASP.NET is the same)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the question, but why not just omit them in the first place instead of trying to remove them?

In your ASPX file....

```
<img src="images/myimage.jpg">
```

And for the love of God, don't try to strip them out with Regex.

Comment: Why not use regex? Genuinely interested. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+height\s*=\s*\S+",
        "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(<img[^>]*?)\s+width\s*=\s*\S+",
        "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: That is exactly the same answer as the one from ridgerunner, minus the text.